# Can't install Gpart in Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: linux, apt, kali-linux, wireshark

When I ran `apt-get install gpart`, I got the following message:

```
apt-get install gpart

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcap0.8 : Breaks: libpcap0.8:i386 (!= 1.4.0-2) but 1.8.1-3 is to be installed
 libpcap0.8:i386 : Breaks: libpcap0.8 (!= 1.8.1-3) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
 libpcap0.8-dev : Depends: libpcap0.8 (= 1.8.1-3) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
 tcpdump : Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
 tshark : Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
 wireshark-common : Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
 wireshark-qt : Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried:

```
apt-get install -f
apt-get autoremove
apt-get purge
```

Any suggestions?
BTW i tried to remove "libpcap" and it still same...

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the removal of libpcap package:

```
# apt-get -f remove libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8-dev:i386 libpcap0.8-dev
```

Then try to install gpart:

```
# apt-get install gpart
```

Comment: Thx but error stays same(why peoples are  downvoting